# How to override all multiple keyframes at once?

Tags: animation

[image]

Hello. Is there anyway you can override multiple keyframes at once? I need to apply rotation of just one bone in all the frames.

I could click each frame and pasted its rotations value. But I assume theres a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's what you want but let say you want your object to be rotated on its X axis all along the animation: Open the *Graph Editor*, lock all the tracks, unlock the track on which you want to make your operation (*X Euler Rotation*), select all (as everything except the X Euler Rotation is locked it will only select the X Euler Rotation curve) and move it on the Y axis of the *Graph Editor* (<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>) until it is rotated the way you want it to be.

[image]